# Virtual Box doesn't install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

I am currently trying out virtual box and wanted to setup a UBUNTU 64bit machine, I am using the most uptodate Ubuntu ISO and VirtualBox Exe.

When I setup a VM, everything works as expected, but then, it will hang on this screen:
[image]

And it never continues any further.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is more a Windows + VB question. Maybe try another VB version, etc. Mayne some BIOS or Windows settings are needed.

Comment: Do you get a menu if you press Esc here? If so, can you launch Ubuntu from there?

Comment: @fkraiem No, when I press ESC nothing happens.

Comment: @Pilot6 What settings would you suggest?

Comment: I have no idea. I am not using Windows. On Ubuntu I install other Ubuntu distros with no problems.

Comment: Maybe try another Ubuntu version, like 18.04.

Comment: Have you enabled Virtualization in BIOS ? If not, or if it isn't available, you can only run 32 bit Os's in VirtualBox.

Comment: @SorenA Virtualisation is on

Comment: Did you enable 3D acceleration in Video of VB?

Comment: This really sounds like a windows question, while you may run into someone who is a windows expert here, it'd be more fruitful to ask on either https://forums.virtualbox.org/ or https://www.tenforums.com/

Comment: Your only problem with Ubuntu is likely to be a bad download (did you `md5sum` or verify the download?   If you hit a key when that *person-in-circle & keyboard* appear you'll get a menu item which will let you check your media), but if not that I'd agree it's a windows/virtual.box config issue (which is not Ubuntu)

Comment: @all I accidentally deinstalled HyperV incorrect and it was interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HyperV was deinstalled incorrectly and interfered with Virtual Box.

Check that all your old VM's are deinstalled correctly.